# Zend cache do we need to create a new object each time?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Through out our application we have something very similar to this:

```
$cache  = App_Cache::getInstance()->newObject(300);
$sig = App_Cache::getCacheName(sha1($sql));
$res = $cache->load($sig);
if ($res === false) {
    $res = $db->fetchAll($sql);
    $cache->save($res, $sig);
}
```

The problem at the moment is that we end up creating a new object of Zend_Cache each time and for each request this can end up getting called 300+ times.

```
class App_Cache {

    protected static $_instance = null;
    public static $enabled = true;
    protected $frontend = null;
    protected $backend = null;
    protected $lifetime = null;

    public function __construct() { }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (is_null(self::$_instance))
            self::$_instance = new self();
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function newObject($lifetime = 0) {
        return Zend_Cache::factory('Core','Memcached',$this->getFrontend($lifetime),$this->getBackend());
    }

    public static function getCacheName($suffix) {
        $suffix = str_replace(array("-","'","@",":"), "_",$suffix);
        return "x{$suffix}";
    }
```

In [Magento](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/master/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php) they seem to create it once in the __construct, where as Concrete5 create a static property.

My question is whats the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `getInstance()` method should be returning your instance of Zend_Cache rather than App_Cache. Try something like this:

```
class App_Cache 
{
  protected static $_instance = null;
  protected static $_cacheInstance = null;
  public static $enabled = true;
  protected $frontend = null;
  protected $backend = null;
  protected $lifetime = null;

  public function __construct() { }

  public static function getInstance() {
    if (is_null(self::$_instance))
        self::$_instance = new self();
    return self::$_instance;
  }

  public function newObject($lifetime = 0) {
    if (is_null(self::$_cacheInstance))
      self::$_cacheInstance = Zend_Cache::factory('Core','Memcached',$this->getFrontend($lifetime),$this->getBackend());
    return self::$_cacheInstance;
  }

  public static function getCacheName($suffix) {
    $suffix = str_replace(array("-","'","@",":"), "_",$suffix);
    return "x{$suffix}";
  }
}
```

<strike>Notice that I changed the `newObject()` method to be static and added the parameter for it into `getInstance()`. In this way, you can call `getInstance()` throughout your code and it will only create the Zend_Cache instance once and then save it in the App_Cache object's `$_instance` variable.</strike>

Ok, changed the code to hold a static instance of the Zend_Cache object and return it if requested. This will only create the instance once. I think the method name should be changed to getCache() or something like that so it's clearer what it is doing.

Comment: Thank you and nice idea. Although I am getting: ` Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in` from the getFrontend(). Also would there be a way to do this without changing params in the getInstance. This is already referenced in lots of different places in the application code and previous projects